# Julia - Is it possible to use a progress bar and Threads.@threads in same for loop?

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, progress-bar, julia

Suppose I have this for loop:

```
for i in 1:100000
   1+1 
   # Let's do some long computations here
end
```

Those two for loops work:

```
Threads.@threads for i in 1:100000
   1+1 
   # Let's do some long computations here
end

using ProgressMeter
@showprogress 1 "Computing..." for i in 1:100000
   1+1 
   # Let's do some long computations here
end
```

But none of the following works:

```
@showprogress 1 "Computing..." Threads.@threads for i in 1:100000
   1+1 
   # Let's do some long computations here
end

using ProgressMeter
Threads.@threads @showprogress 1 "Computing..." for i in 1:100000
   1+1 
   # Let's do some long computations here
end
```

So is it possible in Julia to have parallelism in a for loop as well as a Progress bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works nicely:

```
using ProgressMeter
N = 200
p = Progress(N);
update!(p,0)
jj = Threads.Atomic{Int}(0)

l = Threads.SpinLock()
Threads.@threads for i in 1:N
   sum(rand(10_000_000)) # some big computation
   Threads.atomic_add!(jj, 1)
   Threads.lock(l)
   update!(p, jj[])
   Threads.unlock(l)  
end
```

If you do not want to use locks you might also consider updating only on the first thread (however in that case the progress bar runs less smoothly):

```
Threads.threadid() == 1 && update!(p, jj[])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, when I add this to my for loop Julia stops at its first iteration whereas it worked before. Surprisingly, Julia returns to shell prompt: Julia console crashes. And even more surprisingly, Julia leaves no error, no stacktrace or message, making hard to know why it crashed... That is the first time that happens to me coding in Julia, I always had at least an error message.

Comment: most likely inside your multithreded loop you have a function that is not compiled at the time it gets executed and you run into a multithreaded compilation chase. This always crashes Julia in a hard way. First check if my example works (it should)? If it works try running the code that is inside the multithtreaded loop once in a single thread this will cause the code to compile. Then run the main lopp. Unfortunately the multithreading support is experimental and there are many tricks to get it working. I always recommend using multiprocessing instead (if only possible).